# Netbeans 8 - Apache Tomcat 8 - Log View empty

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I'm running a Maven Web project in Netbeans 8.0 using the Apache tomcat 8 server that is installed be default.  I have a tab in my output window called "Apache Tomcat 8 Log" but nothing ever shows up in it.

I also have a tab called "Apache Tomcat 8" which does show output, but if my javabeans do System.out.prinln I can't seem to find the results anywhere.

Assistance?

Thanks!

== edit ==

I believe i need to maybe use? swallowOutput=true?  Not sure exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: https://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/tomcat_log_files

Q: Why is one of the logs ('Apache Tomcat 6.0.16 Log') empty?

In /apache-tomcat-6.0.16_base/conf/logging.properties, you will notice that, except for catalina logs, the logging level for all the other logs are reset to 'INFO' (while catalina is left at 'FINE' level). This is default tomcat behaviour. This means, unless there are any errors or informational messages, localhost log will be empty. You can:

Stop the tomcat server and close the ide
Open /apache-tomcat-6.0.16_base/conf/logging.properties
Change org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO to org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINE
Restart the ide and start the tomcat server. The file 'Apache Tomcat 6.0.16 Log' should have some info in it now.
Notes

Though the the above is specific to NetBeans 6.1, the concepts should apply to other NetBeans versions as well.
For more on tomcat logging: Tomcat Documentation URL